# Auto-exposure doesn't work Android Camera API v1

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to use camera features as part of my application and I'm stuck on camera preview step.

I want to understand why the preview image remains dark if there are no bright light.
Here is what params I set before start previewing:

```
mParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes = mParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
Camera.Size optimalSize = CameraHelper.getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, DEFAULT_PREVIEW_WIDTH, DEFAULT_PREVIEW_HEIGHT);

// Use the same size for recording profile.
mProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
mProfile.videoFrameWidth = optimalSize.width;
mProfile.videoFrameHeight = optimalSize.height;

// likewise for the camera object itself.
mParameters.setPreviewSize(mProfile.videoFrameWidth, mProfile.videoFrameHeight);

// Set correct video width and height according to screen rotation
transformMatrixHelper.setVideoDimensions(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    transformMatrixHelper.setVideoDimensions(optimalSize.height, optimalSize.width);
}
transformMatrixHelper.clearInitTextureDimension();

mParameters.setPreviewFpsRange(MAX_FPS, MAX_FPS);
mParameters.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);

// Auto-focus
if (mParameters.getSupportedFocusModes().contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
    mParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
}

// Auto-exposure
if (mParameters.isAutoExposureLockSupported()) {
    mParameters.setAutoExposureLock(false);
}

mCamera.setParameters(mParameters);
```

I'm not calling any `camera.autoFocus(callback)` method after preview stared.
I will be very grateful if someone help me, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this on more than one device? It could be a device-specific issue.

Comment: Hi Jarett, I have tested on Nexus 5, Nexus 6 and OnePlus One. And it's not working on any of them. I found that when I start recording auto-exposure working.... But only when i start recording...